# get lowest value in the array based on variable

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am struggling to get the lowest value based on the answer of the client.

```php
$client_answer = 28;

$array = array(10,20,30,40,50);
```

The answer that should be given is: 20

So every answer should be rounded down to the lower number.

Other examples:

```php
$client_answer = 37;

$array = array(10,20,30,40,50);
```

answer should be 30.

---

```php
$client_answer = 14;

$array = array(10,20,30,40,50);
```

answer should be 10.

---

```php
$client_answer = 45;

$array = array(10,20,30,40,50);
```

answer should be 40.

---

Is there a php function that I can use for this?

If not how can this be accomplished?

Comment: Yes, but you have to write it :) Have you tried to write anything yet?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes I have but unfortunately It would pick the closest number... But I think Qirel fixed my question. Thanks for your time!

Comment: What if your answer falls out of the range of numbers in the array?

Comment: @Progrock with the answer of Qirel it wil take the closest. This is exactly what I needed. (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter the array to only contain values equal to or below the given value `$client_answer`, then use `max()` on the filtered array.

```
$value = max(array_filter($array, function($v) use ($client_answer) {
    return $v <= $client_answer;
}));
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/KHB8r

Answer (score -1):

This might be a very stupid answer, but in this specific case, you are trying to truncate the unit number? Why not try this:

```
$client_answer = intdiv( $client_answer, 10) * 10;
```

Divide by 10, get rid of the last digit, and multiply again.
EDIT : typo

Comment: Except OP is trying to pick a number out of an array?

Comment: the array could be any number so this would unfortunatly not work... thanks for your time though!

Answer (score -1):

Only this rounds correctly

```
$client_answer = 28;
$array = array(10,20,30,40,50);
rsort($array,1);
$min_diff = max($array);
$closest_val = max($array);

foreach($array as $val)
{
    if(abs($client_answer - $val) < $min_diff)
    {
        $min_diff = abs($client_answer - $val);
        $closest_val = $val;
    }

}
echo $closest_val;
```

Comment: My question has already been solved. Thanks for taking the time though! This looks like a good alternative

Comment: The suggested solution does not find the nearest value it always rounds down... but I am glad if that cover your needs.

Comment: You are returning the nearest number in the array, not the lowest nearest.  https://3v4l.org/0Qfnm